# Failure in pairing bluetooth device in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: bluetooth, connection, 21.04

I see that failure in pairing Bluetooth devices is commonplace. I have Ubuntu 21.04,
I plugged a [Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter Dongle](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07NQ5YGDW/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), the device (headphones) is visible but no pairing is obtained. I checked the status of the Bluetooth and it seems to me it is running:

```
sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-27 09:54:30 CEST; 57min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1738 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38312)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1738 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 27 10:12:11 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: src/device.c:search_cb() E8:AB:FA:>
Sep 27 10:14:13 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Pair device timed out for hci0
Sep 27 10:16:36 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Pair device timed out for hci0
Sep 27 10:19:29 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Pair device timed out for hci0
Sep 27 10:19:33 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Sep 27 10:19:35 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Sep 27 10:43:13 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Pair device timed out for hci0
Sep 27 10:45:25 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Sep 27 10:45:35 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Sep 27 10:49:00 juggernaut bluetoothd[1738]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Make and model of the headphones?

Comment: Active Noise Cancelling Kopfhörer, Boltune Kabellos Bluetooth 5.0 . Could it be that the adapter is 4.0 thus it doe snot work?

Comment: Could be. You would need to get a 5.0 dongle to test.

Comment: UPDATE: I plugged a B.T. 5 (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B098K3H92Z/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), I got a screen similar to the one in the main question, but now no devices are available at all, for instance in setting>Bluetooth...

Comment: Looks like ti was a hardware problem: with https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B08B9WQFTL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1 it plugged immediately and effortless. However, I don't have sound apart from the alert sounds. The headset is recognized, the test sound works, clementine and spotify show 100% sound volume but then nothing happens...